# BigQuery For Loop Results into Python smtplib Message Body

Tags: python, google-bigquery, smtplib

I want to grab data from a BigQuery database at a set interval and have the results emailed automatically using smtplib.

I have an example below. I can pull data from BigQuery just fine. I can send email via smtplib just fine. What I need to do is combine. I want to store the results of a for loop into the email body of the message. I believe I do that by calling the function. However when I do that. I receive the error.

> File "bqtest5.py", line 52, in  server.sendmail(login_email,
>   recipients, query_named_params('corpus',  'min_word_count')) File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 729, in sendmail
>   esmtp_opts.append("size=%d" % len(msg)) TypeError: object of type
>   'NoneType' has no len()

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import smtplib

#Variables
login_email = 'MYEMAIL'
login_pwd = 'MYPASSWORD'
recipients ='EMAILSENDINGTO'


#Create a function
#specifies we are going to add two paramaters
def query_named_params(corpus, min_word_count):
    #Create a Client
    client = bigquery.Client()
    #Define the query
    query = """
        SELECT word, word_count
        FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`
        WHERE corpus = @corpus
        AND word_count >= @min_word_count
        ORDER BY word_count DESC;
        """
    #Define the paramaters
    query_params = [
        bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter('corpus', 'STRING', 'sonnets'),
        bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter(
            'min_word_count', 'INT64', 10)
    ]
    #Create job configuration
    job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
    #Add Query paramaters
    job_config.query_parameters = query_params
    #P
    query_job = client.query(query, job_config=job_config)

    # Print the results.
    destination_table_ref = query_job.destination
    table = client.get_table(destination_table_ref)
    resulters = client.list_rows(table)
    for row in resulters:
        print("{} : {} views".format(row.word, row.word_count))

# --------------------EMAIL PORTION -------------#
#)smtplib connection    print('messenger()')
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(login_email, login_pwd)

msg = """

"""
server.sendmail(login_email, recipients, query_named_params('corpus', 
'min_word_count'))
server.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    query_named_params('corpus','min_word_count')
```

Comment: Replace `msg` with `messenger()` ?

Comment: That gives me the error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bqtest4.py", line 53, in <module>
    query_named_params('corpus','min_word_count')
  File "bqtest4.py", line 48, in query_named_params
    server.sendmail(login_email, recipients, messenger())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 729, in sendmail
    esmtp_opts.append("size=%d" % len(msg))
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

So the function is returning None when called there but it returns results if I just print it on the page. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not returning any value which causes an empty message to be sent to `server.sendmail`.

Try this instead:

```
def query_named_params(corpus, min_word_count):

    (...)

    query_params = [
        bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter('corpus', 'STRING', corpus),
        bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter(
            'min_word_count', 'INT64', min_word_count)
    ]

    (...)
    s = ""
    for row in resulters:
        s+= "{} : {} views\n".format(row.word, row.word_count))
    return s

(...)
server.sendmail(login_email, recipients, query_named_params('sonnets', 10))
```

This probably will not send a very readable message though. Depending on the complexity of the results from your BQ table I'd recommend using [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/) to create a HTML template and then rendering it to be sent as the mail body.

Comment: This helps put a lot of things together. It prints fine to the terminal, however it still doesn't show up in the email. Meaning I can do a print(query_named_params('corpus', 'min_word_count') and the rows print out. But they don't return when sending out the email in the body.

Comment: you should give `corpus` a value, otherwise it's not defined for the interpreter, something like: `print(query_named_params('sonnets', 10))`

Comment: If I do that here

server.sendmail(login_email, recipients, query_named_params('sonnets', '10'))

It still returns nothing in the email body. Also what I am trying to do is use query parameters in the search. This is Shakespeare part is an example, ultimately I want to be able to pass a date string into the query and other variables. Then return the results of that to the email. It seems like that part is getting tripped up.

Comment: what is the output of `print(query_named_params('sonnets', 10))`?

Comment: It returns all of the results.

It seems like when the function is called into server.sendmail() either the output of the data or the data type or the result being given isn't compatible in some way.

Example
the : 363 views
of : 351 views
I : 342 views
my : 335 views
to : 335 views
in : 287 views
and : 247 views
And : 242 views
thy : 240 views

Comment: and what is the output of `print(query_named_params('sonnets', '10'))` (the last "10" being a str that is)

Comment: I get the same output as a string

Comment: hmm weird. Just as your previous question I fully tested your code and it's working for me; there's some bug somewhere in your code. Make sure you are calling the method as `server.sendmail(login_email, recipients, query_named_params('sonnets', 10))`, other than that you'll have to find where the bug is.

Comment: I appreciate all the help! I will keep plugging away and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164202/discussion-between-jeff-and-willian-fuks).